# Unable to update observable value in subscribe method

Tags: knockout.js, subscribe

I have a subscribe function which fires when the dropdown value changes. I want to update another observable value inside this subscribe function. The probelm is when the control leaves this subscribe function the observable value got null or empty.

```
self.selectedSubAccount.subscribe(function (newValue) {
 //alert("The Selected Account Code:" + newValue);
 var likeCode = newValue.substring(0, 2);
 var accType = "Control";
 self.ACCOUNT_CODE = GenrateAccountCode(self.SUBACCOUNTS(), likeCode, accType);
});
```

Comment: Which property is observable in your code? Is it the `self.ACCOUNT_CODE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `self.ACCOUNT_CODE` is your observable, you would update it like so:

```
self.ACCOUNT_CODE(GenrateAccountCode(self.SUBACCOUNTS(), likeCode, accType));
```